# Setting javascript variables with if-else statements based on $_POST value

Tags: php, javascript, variables, if-statement, undefined

I've got a form that contains radio button options which I would like to use to dictate the values of a set of variables.

The radio buttons are as follows:

```
<table style="width:90%">
<tr><td><input type="radio" id="opt1" name ="selectOpt" value="option1"
checked="checked"/> Option 1</td><td><input type="radio" id="opt2" name ="selectOpt"
value="option2"/> Option 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm able to echo the value of the radio button with

```
<p id="selection">
<?php echo $_POST["selectOpt"];?></p>
```

so I am certain that the variable is being carried over. Since I am passing the $_POST value to an element so that the user sees what value was selected, I figured I would use the element ID to grab the value for my if-else statements.

Here is what my if-else statement looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var template = $("#selection").text();

if(template == 'option1'){
var part1 = "beautifulweather";
var part2 = "ishouldgooutside";
}

else if(template == 'option2'){
var part1 = "isthatrain";
var part2 = "imstayinginside";
}

weather = "www.weather.com/" + part1 + "ithink" + part2;
```

I then pass this URL to a button that has an empty href with the following lines:

```
var a = document.getElementById('weatherbtn');
a.href = weather;
```

However, whenever I click the link, part1 & part 2 appear as undefined. I've used document.write(template, part1, part2) after the if-else and confirmed that it prints option1undefinedundefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

**SOLVED**

General formatting issues that I needed to change (as pointed out by nearly everyone here): I needed to declare my variables first and remove the var keyword from the variables being assigned in my if-else statements (part1/part2).

I also bypassed the

element and passed the echo directly in the template variable. Working code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
var part1, part2, template;
var template = '<?php echo $_POST["selectOpt"];?>';

if(template == 'option1'){
part1 = "beautifulweather";
part2 = "ishouldgooutside";
}

else if(template == 'option2'){
part1 = "isthatrain";
part2 = "imstayinginside";
}
```

weather = "www.weather.com/" + part1 + "ithink" + part2;

Thanks, everybody - especially cdhowie for the note about JS not being block-scoped. That was driving me nuts.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  Is this JS and the buttons all on the same page or are you trying to pass the values of the radio buttons through to another page via POST?

Comment: You are missing a closing `"` character on the line `var template = ...`.  Is this just a copy and paste error?

Comment: is that a typo: `$("#selection).text();` you are missing a double-quote.

Comment: `var template = $("#selection :selected").val();` 
1. Double-quotes missing. 
2. If you want the actual selected value, you have to add `:selected` to your jQuery-selector. 
3. Use `val()` instead of `text()` to get the actually selected value of your dropdown.

Comment: @JamesAlday - Sorry for the confusing presentation. This is HTML/JS/PHP and the radio buttons are located on a previous page (input.html). A radio button is selected and a button is pressed to submit the value, taking the user to output.php with the value displayed by <p><?php echo $_POST["selectOpt"];?></p>

Comment: @cdhowie yeah, sorry about that. fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the problems I see:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var template = $("#selection).text();
    //                          ^
    // Missing closing quote mark

    if(template == 'option1'){
        var part1 = "beautifulweather";
        var part2 = "ishouldgooutside";
    }

    else if(template == 'option2'){
        var part1 = "isthatrain";
        var part2 = "imstayinginside";
        // Duplicate definition of variables.  JavaScript is not block-scoped.
    }

    // It's possible that the template variable does not match either string.
    // Therefore, the part1 and part2 variables might not be assigned here.

    weather = "www.weather.com/" + part1 + "ithink" + part2;
```

To fix the first two problems:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Always declare variables first!
    var template, part1, part2;

    template = $("#selection").text();
    // Add quote mark       ^

    if(template == 'option1'){
        // Remove "var" keyword.
        part1 = "beautifulweather";
        part2 = "ishouldgooutside";
    }

    else if(template == 'option2'){
        // Remove "var" keyword.
        part1 = "isthatrain";
        part2 = "imstayinginside";
    }

    weather = "www.weather.com/" + part1 + "ithink" + part2;
```

To fix the third issue (`template` not matching either string) consider displaying the value of `template` via, for example, `alert(JSON.stringify(template))` while you are debugging.  It's possible (and likely, given your markup) that the string contains some whitespace characters.  I expect that the solution will be to change your markup to:

```
<p id="selection"><?php echo $_POST["selectOpt"];?></p>
```

Comment: I've been using document.write(template) to check what value is being returned and it returns option1 and option2 correctly. I've fixed the first two errors, though. Could it have to do with using .text() rather than .val() like alexP states?

Comment: @Rooncicle If it is truly a `<p>` element, then no, `.text()`, is indeed what you want.  Did you `JSON.stringify()` the value before writing it to the document?  As I said, it probably contains whitespace characters that the HTML parser is going to collapse.  You need to encode the value into a format where whitespace characters are obvious.  (Consider using both `JSON.stringify()`, and putting the result in a `<pre>` tag -- stringify will make newlines obvious, and the `<pre>` will make spaces obvious.  Or, better yet, use a JavaScript debugger.)

Comment: thanks! I bypassed the <p> element and passed the echo value directly into template, along with removing the var keywords from part1/part2 and declaring my variables before the if-else statement. I'll post my fixed code right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="selection">
<?php echo $_POST["selectOpt"];?></p>
```

The id is not part of the styling. So you have to remove that from the

Tag, else the id is unset and `$("#selection)` won't return an object. So use the code above and it should work.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your variables outside of the if/else

```
var part1;
var part2;
if(template == 'option1'){
    part1 = "beautifulweather";
    part2 = "ishouldgooutside";
}

else if(template == 'option2'){
    part1 = "isthatrain";
    part2 = "imstayinginside";
}
```